# AWS Cloudformation trouble with VPC and Autoscalled Windows instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to combine the Cloud formation template multi-tier-web-app-in-vpc.template with the cloudformation template used by viusal studio to create Load Balanced instances. The goal is to create 2 application servers within a private subnet of a VPC. The template works fine but when I start plugging in windows instances they just fail. 
Error Message
CREATE_FAILED WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1 
The following resource(s) failed to create: [FrontendWaitCondition]. . Rollback requested by user.

Template used to create the cloud formation
https://s3.amazonaws.com/hg-optimise/Windows-Multi-Tier.template

I am trying to use the following Amazon templates as guides.

Amazon Visual Studio Template
https://s3.amazonaws.com/hg-optimise/Visual-Studio.template

Amazon Multi-tier Web Sample - http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/multi-tier-web-app-in-vpc.template

Comment: Can you post the template that you are using?

Comment: I see you updated the question, but I don't see the template that you used.   Anyway, it looks like what you're trying to do is too complex to troubleshoot at once.  It would be good to start out just with an Autoscaling group and launch config, then add a load balancer, then work with vpc, etc.

Comment: The template I am using https://s3.amazonaws.com/hg-optimise/Windows-Multi-Tier.template

Comment: I have tried a few different versions of this template but no matter how I slice it, it always fails to Create the WaitCondition, Its frustrating because beankstalk works just fine in the vpc, so I know it can be done and I am just missing something.

Comment: I have the same issue with the CloudFormation auto generated by Elastic Beanstalk. Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are taking on too much, trying to get everything working all at once.  I would try to take it one step at a time.  Create a template that gets one instance up, then add auto scaling, then load balancer, then subnet, routing, etc.  The problem that presents itself now is likely because you have not signaled success for the wait condition.

Below is the Properties section of an Instance resource.  This snipet was taken from an AWS [documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/example-templates-autoscaling.html). Note that the "UserData" section has a call to cfn-init.exe in order to perform the actions specified in the Instance's Cloud Formation  section, and has a call to cfn-signal.exe to signal to the WaitCondition that the instance is up.

```
"Properties": {
  "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
  "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
  "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "SharePointFoundationSecurityGroup"} ],
  "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyPairName" },
  "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
    "<script>\n",

    "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
    " -r SharePointFoundation",
    " --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

    "cfn-signal.exe -e %ERRORLEVEL% ", { "Fn::Base64" : { "Ref" : "SharePointFoundationWaitHandle" }}, "\n",

    "</script>"
    ]]}}
  }
```

Comment: I have tried calling cfn-signal.exe directly but I recieved the error WaitCondition received failed message: 'Configuration failed.' for uniqueId: i-9371f6bd. The only differance was I removed the "-r SharePointFoundation"

I have broked this down pretty far, I got the network up and running, and I have gotten the windows instances up and running, now I am trying to merge the 2. I will try and break it down a little further, by cleaning up the visual studio template, which has the instance and auto scaling working, but is in a different format than the multi-tier template.

Comment: Finally I am getting back to this project, the main problem I have is that the Visual Studio tool hides some of the parameters. I am not finished yet but I have started with a simpler template to figure out how to deploy the IIS application.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the front end wait condition to basically wait until your FrontendFleet is up and running. 
You should set a desired capacity for your front end fleet.

When you get this error, what is the state of your autoscaling group FrontendFleet? If this is still bringing up instances, then your timeout is simply to short.

I honestly wouldn't worry about the waitcondtions unless you really need them.

Comment: I have tried both with and without the desired capacity, it did not seem to work. The autoscaling seems to be functioning and the instance seems to be ready. I have tried a 3600s time out, it still failed it just took longer. 

I guess I am a worry wort, but you are probably right I could just move on and circle back :)